# How to do Group By with the DATEADD for wanted result

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am writing a function to calculate the total number of Mails received in each month. But using Group By DATEADD function get only  the non o count values only.
I need to get the all values within the 0 counts.

SELECT (MAX(ReceivedMonthofYear)+' '+MAX(ReceivedYear)) AS MonthStartDate,COUNT(ReceivedDateTime) AS MonthlyTotal 
FROM tblMessageReceived 
    GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, ReceivedDateTime), 0)

This resulted Query
[image: Out put of the query]

Actually I want to get the output of the all values in given range by with also 0 count values and months also.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a `DATE` table containing all available dates.

Comment: @sagi Using All the DATE table how to do that. If using DATE table Left OUTERJOIN with the tblMessageReceived .

Comment: When you have dates table, select from it and left join to your query, and use ISNULL to replace null with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT td.monthCol+' '+td.yearCol AS MonthStartDate,
       isnull(MonthlyTotal,0) AS MonthlyTotal
FROM tblDates td
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT (MAX(ReceivedMonthofYear)+' '+MAX(ReceivedYear)) AS MonthStartDate,
                        COUNT(ReceivedDateTime) AS MonthlyTotal 
                 FROM tblMessageReceived 
                 GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, ReceivedDateTime), 0)) tm
 ON (td.monthCol+' '+td.yearCol = tm.MonthStartDate)
```

Try this, replace MonthCol and YearCol with your date table column names